# SPSite-BackUp and .Backup c# method

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, development

i am creating a C# GUI to easily back up and restore SharePoint site collections as little project and experiment.

Using Powershell i can do it with

```
Backup-SPSite [-Identity] <SPSitePipeBind> -Path <String> [-AssignmentCollection <SPAssignmentCollection>] [-Confirm [<SwitchParameter>]] [-Force <SwitchParameter>] [-NoSiteLock <SwitchParameter>] [-UseSqlSnapshot <SwitchParameter>] [-WhatIf [<SwitchParameter>]]`
```

Using C# instead i am using the method

```
mySiteCols.Backup(site.Url, siteColsBackUpPath, true);
```

My question is:
Will Sharepoint, using c# method, put the Site Collection while executing the backup in read only mode as done with the powershell command **NoSiteLock**?

My concern is

> If users are writing to the site collection while the site collection is being backed up, then the NoSiteLock parameter is not recommended for potential impact to backup integrity
>   Source: https://technet.microsoft.com/it-it/library/ff607901.aspx

Thank you all in advance